# Remove middle name, initial, or nothing from character vector

Tags: r, char

I have a vector of names like so:

```
x <- c("bob smith", "greg a taylor", "lindsey louise brown")
```

so each entry is a name firstname lastname with either nothing between, or a middle initial or the whole middle name. What I want to do is remove the information about the middle name where it exists, so I should get

```
"bob smith", "greg taylor", "lindsey brown"
```

as the output. How is this possible in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `capture groups`

```
sub('^(\\w+).*\\b(\\w+)$', '\\1 \\2', x)
#[1] "bob smith"     "greg taylor"   "lindsey brown"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use sub

```
sub("\\s+\\S+(?=\\s)", '',s, perl=TRUE)
```

or

```
sub("\\s+\\S+(\\s)", '\\1',s, perl=TRUE)
```