# Removing middle initial from end of string in R

Tags: r, regex

Need help removing the middle initial from the end of a string, but am not sure how to write the regex pattern out to do this in R.

Vector like:

```
x <- c("SMITH, BOB A.", "BISHOP, MATTHEW", "CLARK, CORY B")
```

Desired output:

```
[1] "SMITH, BOB"    "BISHOP, MATTHEW"    "CLARK, CORY"
```

Tried the following, but it may be way off

```
test <- sub('^(\\w+)(\\W)(\\h)(\\w+)(\\h).*\\b$', '\\1 \\2',vec2)
```

Tried to replicate the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34515784/8691583) from this other post, but don't think it's quite right.

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like R regex is the same as `grep`, so you could easily build up a solution based on https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Comment: I want to ask why, but based on your examples`\s+[A-Z]\b\.?$`?

Comment: @ctwheels - tried that just a second ago and got this Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\s"

As for the why - I am trying to merge two data frames using the names. I have data from two different databases - one db adds in all the middle initials, and the other does not add in the middle initials - so they aren't merging completely

Comment: @jdv - Thanks! I'll take a look at it

Comment: Perhaps of use are those online regular expression engines. You can cut a lot of development time by using one of those.

Comment: @jdv - Oooh didn't know that was a thing - Great idea!

Comment: @BishopBHM you need to escape the backslashes and you may need to pass `perl=T` to the function

Comment: @Jan you're right, totally overlooked that fact: `\s+[A-Z]\.?$` (which I guess is your answer haha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
x <- c("SMITH, BOB A.", "BISHOP, MATTHEW", "CLARK, CORY B")
gsub("(.*)\\s+[A-Z]\\.?$", "\\1", x)
```

Which yields

```
[1] "SMITH, BOB"      "BISHOP, MATTHEW" "CLARK, CORY"
```

Comment: what will be the problem of using a pattern like `\\s[A-Z]?.$`. I believe this will not even need the backreference . We will just substitute the captured string with empty string. ie `sub('\\s[A-Z]?.$','',x)`

Comment: @Onyambu: A couple of problems, really, see https://regex101.com/r/hfZwGC/1 If you do not escape the dot, you mean **every character** which could as well be a whitespace, a digit, a comma, etc. Additionally, your expression does not account for multiple whitespaces (which might or might not be there).

Comment: Thanks. I get the reasoning behind your \\s+, and behind the escape. But I still cannotunderstand why (.*).. Why capture this and still output it in the back reference? Why not just substitute the captured part of the string with empty.?

Comment: @Onyambu: You could totally do that, several ways are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first two words in a string, where words are delimited by spaces, with

```
stringr::word(x, 1, 2)
```